# How are inputs protected through a KVM switch?

Tags: security, keyboard-video-mouse

If there are multiple computers connected to a KVM switch, can all computers on that switch *potentially* log keystokes/mouse movements/other inputs that are **not** designated for it?

**Example:**

- 4 computers connected to KVM switch
- Computer "1" is selected

  - Computer 1 is now being passed the keyboard and mouse input
  - Computer 1's screens are showing on dual monitors

**Questions:**

- Is there monitoring software that can run on Computer "2" (or "3" or "4") to read/log keystrokes from Computer 1?
- Or is the input "secured"/protected from the other computers on the KVM switch?
- Anyone heard of this type of concern before?

Comment: Historically, those would be *cables* with a giant multi-switch, so impossible to read anything unless selected. Today, as with many other complex devices speaking USB, this may be as "simple" as uploading a new firmware version. Consider asking this in a [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or hardware hacking context, though.